# Getting Error "Namespace Name "Contacts" Does Not Exists" in spite of using using "Google.GData.Contacts"?

Tags: c#, email, google-data-api

I want to create Contact on Google Apps.
I am Using this [API](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google%20Data%20API%20Setup%281.4.0.2%29.msi&can=2&q=)

And referring [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Audience)

**In below code i am using "Using Google.GData.Contacts"** :

```
using Google.GData.Contacts;   // Using Google.GData.Contacts     
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.Contacts; // at this place i am getting error
```

**Error**: The type or namespace name 'Contacts' does not exist in the namespace 'Google' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**I have included Google.GData.Contacts API**. But still it is giving Error.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? m i missing any Assembly reference?

I want to use:

```
Contact newContact = new Contact();
newContact.Title.Text = "Liz Doe";
```

"Contact" does not exist in Either "Google.GData.Contacts" or "Google.GData". 
Is there any other way to use it?

Comment: Are you compiling using Visual Studio? You have already added reference to Google.GData.Contacts.dll, right?

Comment: ya..i have already added this ddl. And am Compiling code also.Using Visual Studio 2005

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using Wrong version.
use Version: 1.4.0.2.

You will find it in Program Files Path

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer:

using Google.**GData**.Contacts;

Comment: The code you have posted is missing the GData from your using statement.

Comment: You have a duplicate entry.  Remove the bottom reference to Google.Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ardman already noted, this should probably be enough:

using Google.GData.Contacts;

but you also have a line:

using Google.Contacts;

Either the second using is wrong and you need to remove it, or that namespace resides in 1 or more assemblies you have not referenced yet.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
using Google.GData;
```

Comment: even this does not helped. I am anable to use "Contact newContact = new Contact(); " code .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website, I'm guessing that there is a seperate reference that you need to add in order to use Google.Contacts.  Check your references to see if you have a seperate Google.Contacts library which you can reference.

Comment: I have downloaded Google API from Above link.
And i din't found any reference (library) like "Google.Contacts".
m i using wrong Google API.I searched it on Net but din't found any other api.

Comment: I downloaded the API and added a reference to Google.GData.Contacts.DLL and this then gave me the Google.Contacts namespace in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/dotnet_client_lib.htmt
Check if you are following it or not.